# Paste option disabled for hard disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and along with windows 10. Previously I was able to copy/paste files without any problem. I used to work with windows 10 rarely. Once after working with windows 10(only once) now I can't able to paste in hard disk. But, I can able to copy files. Paste option is disabled which means greyed out.

This is my mount options:

```
nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,ro,remove_hiberfile
```

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Check that Windows is shutting down properly, and quick start is not enabled in Windows.

Comment: the disk is probably mounted read only because windows hibernated, Quick Start is a hibernation.

Comment: Mount options show `ro` - read-only.